Airflow running in docker swarm. Blank page in UI
I've got Airflow running in docker  swarm:
docker service ls
ID             NAME                            MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                    PORTS
tiyk15p1lz0g   airflow_airflow-init            replicated   0/1        airflow_custom:latest
5w3ndsofmqp1   airflow_airflow-scheduler       replicated   1/1        airflow_custom:latest
plojza90qg3y   airflow_airflow-webserver       replicated   1/1        airflow_custom:latest                       *:8088->8080/tcp
krbjihccx96p   airflow_postgres                replicated   1/1        postgres:13                              *:5432->5432/tcp


While opening UI in browser get just a blank page.

In 20 minutes it may load this way

And logging in leads to Bad Request. The CSRF session token is missing.
Webserver log indicates the following (timestamps not really correlated with browser activiry)
[23] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:42)
[23] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:43)
[23] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:45)
[42] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 42)
[45] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 45)
[43] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 43)
[23] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:44)
[44] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 44)
[23] [ERROR] Worker (pid:43) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[23] [ERROR] Worker (pid:42) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[272] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 272
[23] [ERROR] Worker (pid:45) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[23] [ERROR] Worker (pid:44) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?


I checked memory consumption and it seems to be fine

CONTAINER ID   NAME                        CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O         PIDS
2a92b371f841   airflow_airflow-webserver   5.43%     585.8MiB / 15.61GiB   3.66%     1.08MB / 485kB    0B / 16.4kB       16
18872fa7d2ed   airflow_airflow-scheduler   1.79%     465.7MiB / 15.61GiB   2.91%     29.4MB / 36.2MB   8.19kB / 57.3kB   74
275d045fc40e   airflow_postgres            0.93%     155.5MiB / 15.61GiB   0.97%     38.3MB / 34MB     0B / 8.14MB       19


I also redeployed the stack on another node of the swarm and got exactly the same result.
The airflow image is taken from another setup which is functioning well. Though there were multiple commits in the image.
I tried to spot any kill events, but  dmesg | grep -i kill returned nothing

Question:
What could be causing the Airflow UI to load blank and timeout, and how can I resolve the CSRF session token issue?
